# How to filter or ignore some new logcat messages

Tags: logcat, android-studio-electric-eel

After update on Android Studio Electric Eel (maybe a bit earlier :) )
In my logcat I saw new messages:

```
W set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086
W set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3
W set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2094_40
```

If I'm testing my app on android device with OS Android 5.1 log is clear without such messages, but when I'm using device with OS Android 12 or 13,  logcat always shown this messages, when my app shows progress dialogs or progress indicators.
This is warning messages, and I don't understand how to hide them, or do something to fix this warning.
I use real device to test my apps. If it is meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am seeing a lot of these logs on newer devices as well, not sure where they come from. But with the new logcat filtering, you can filter out these messages ( They all have the IMGMapper Tag), with the following:

```
 -tag:IMGMapper
```

As you can negate filter expressions (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#negation-and-regex)

[image: Image of the logcat filter]

Comment: how to do this in flutter command line? really frustating seeing this.

Comment: not sure about flutter, I think this is an IDE feature